# How to group an anonymous dynamic IQueryable

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I'm using `EFCore 5.0.8` to select a dynamically queried data from `SQL Server 2019` and I'm trying to use the `GroupBy` method on an anonymous `IQueryable` (Non-generic `IQueryable`) which selects on my database.
From the `DebugView` I can see the expression:

> DbSet()
> .Select( => new <>f__AnonymousType1<<>f__AnonymousType0<Nullable, string, string, string,  Nullable, Nullable>>{ Department = new <>f__AnonymousType0<Nullable, string, string, string,  Nullable, Nullable>{
> Departman_Id = .Departman_Id,
> Name = .Name,
> ManagerName = .ManagerName,
> Code = .Code,
> Status = .Status,
> Priority = .Priority
> }
> }
> )
> .Select( => new <>f__AnonymousType2{ Department_Name = .Department.Name }
> )

Which is clearly selecting `Department.Name` as `Department_Name` from the database. The generated query in the `DebugView` is:

> SELECT [d].[Name] AS [Department_Name]
> FROM [Department] AS [d]

Everything is working perfect but when I use `GroupBy` on the queryable, Entity Framework Core is unable to translate it.

```
entities = entities.GroupBy("Department_Name", "new (Department_Name as dummy)");
```

The expression is now appended by:

> .GroupBy(
> keySelector:  => .Department_Name,
> elementSelector:  => new <>f__AnonymousType3{ dummy = .Department_Name }
> )

But fetching the data throws an InvalidOperationException:

> Unable to translate the given 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable' before 'GroupBy' to evaluate it client-side.

And I want it to be:

```
SELECT [d].[Name] AS [Department_Name] FROM [Department] AS [d] GROUP BY [d].[Name]
```

Either I'm not using this overload of `GroupBy` correctly or there is no such feature to generate SQL from `GroupBy` on anonymous queryables. Or is it something else?
The documentations on this overload are poor and there are not enough examples around the web.

Comment: The usual lack of GroupBy support in EF core. Do the grouping in memory, i.e. after getting the results.

Comment: As far as I know, EF core supports grouping, at least they claim it does [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby). EF core converts the expression in an IQueryable to SQL statement, which is what's happening correctly in the generic IQueryable. After a bit of research I'm convinced it's impossible to NOT support GroupBy in non generic IQueryable while supporting it in the generic one. (Take a look at how expressions are translated in EF core.) So why do you say EF core doesn't translate it?

Comment: I don't say that. EF's exception message tells it. GroupBy support is notoriously poor in EF core. Until EF core 5, only GrouBy with an aggregate expression is supported, see the link. EF core 6 will add support for some more, but far from all, GroupBy query patterns.

Comment: @Bamdad `GroupBy` like this is not supported for `IQueryable<T>` as well, because it fails into `IGrouping` returning queries which are not translated (read again the link from your comment). If you want thanslation, `GroupBy` (with or without element selector argument) must be followed by `Select` projecting only key/aggregates. For instance, `.GroupBy("Department_Name").Select("Key")` or `.GroupBy("Department_Name").Select("new (Key as Department_Name)")` or `.GroupBy("new (Key as Department_Name)").Select("Key")` etc.